# How to autolink all words in a rendered text that match an item name in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with a postgres database for articles and items. I would like that whenever I render text from an article, it can somehow scan the text and if it finds a word that matches the name of an item in my database it autolinks to that items show_path.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reason it out from first principles.

Make a little method that returns either a word, or a link to an article if the word is in the article.

```
def make_link(word)
  item = Item.find_by(text: word.downcase)
  item ? link_to(word, item_path(item_id) : word
end
```

Now, map all the words in the article using the method above to convert the linkable ones into links.

```
new_article = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(article).split(' ').map{|word| make_link(word)}.join(' ').html_safe
```

Note the `html_safe` method to ensure the link tags aren't escaped when the new_article is rendered, and the `sanitize` method to ensure unwanted HTML tags in the source are removed.

Comment: Thank you!! Your approach sounds great, I will come back with a report in case anyone else is interested.